# Check the latest file exist in FTP and update the status in data base with status flag

Tags: batch-file, ftp, batch-processing

I need your help on to check whether the latest file exist on FTP server and update the status flag in data base with 'Y' Or 'N' in Status column.

If it is not clear kindly let me know.

code :

```
ftp -s open https://secure-transfer.com/
open https://secure-transfer.com/
ftp_test
5zjjvr
cd PR/T4/ImportFileToMI/
bin
prompt
lcd D:\
mget *20121121*.txt
bye
```

batch script:

```
ftp -s:FTPScript.txt
```

I need to update the status as give below..

update tab set status='Y';

Many thanks for your help.

Sunitha.

Comment: What is the problem? You do not know how to test that any file was downloaded using the `ftp.exe` script?

Comment: thnaks for your reply..how to find if the file is exist or not.please help me